# Visual Studio shortcut to get back to coding pane after terminating the run using Shift+F5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

This was very tricky to Google ,however, a very simple question in mind. Instead of wasting lots of time filtering the Google search results I prefer to ask my Stack fellow developers.

**Scenario**

1. Program is running
2. I terminate it using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
3. I want to continue making change to the code **BUT** the focus is on some random *Find Usage* pane (from resharper) instead of the code itself.

I simply don't want to keep pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key until I'm lucky.

Any shortcut available?

Thanks

Comment: It definitely does. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think <kbd>Esc</kbd> consistently does the trick.

You might try/use/want to know about <kbd>Shift-Esc</kbd> too, which just closes that random "find" pane.

---

*Disclaimer* Based on my VS2010 setup involving R#, VisVim and generally C# coding.

Comment: **Esc** works indeed. I should've followed my muscle memory instinct. Also love the **Shift+Esc** combo. Never knew about this one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your cursor to the place you were before with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> for the opposite effect.

Hope to be helpful :)

Comment: Very interesting shortcut :)) Seems I am getting really rusty with shortcuts. Not exactly the answer for this particular question or I would voted it up as an **answer**
Also as a little trick. You can put your Keyboard-Shortcuts inside this tag <kbd>SHift</kbd> to show them in a more sophisticated way as you can see in my post or the @sehe's answer. Your post won't let me edit it or I would do it for you.